# Rails 3.2 - Undefined method compute_public_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Prior to upgrade to Rails 3.2 I had the following code in one of my views:

```
<%= compute_public_path('some_file.m4a', 'media-files') %>
```

After upgrading Rails, I get the following error:

**undefined method `compute_public_path'**

Looking at [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/AssetPaths/compute_public_path), it seems like compute_public_path method had been moved to ActionView::AssetPaths.  However, it is not available in my view layer.

Is it possible to make this function available or are there are any alternatives?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use [`asset_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) instead?